# How to keep Visual Studio autocomplete from overwriting the next word

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete

I have a very annoying problem in Visual Studio. (My version is 2010 and I have ReSharper and VsVim installed, but I don't think that matters.) When I go to add text before some code at the beginning of some existing code, autocomplete likes to overwrite some of the existing code.

Take this example code:

[image: initial code example]

When I begin to insert some code at the beginning of the `string.Format`:

[image]

And then I use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete, it overwrites `string`, whereas what I wanted was the autocompleted code to be inserted before `string`:

[image]

I don't want it to automatically delete the text after what I am autocompleting. If I want the text deleted, I can delete it myself very easily (particularly with VsVim). Is there any way I can prevent this behavior? I find myself working around it all the time.

Comment: I would love to know how to fix this as well. It happens to me all the time and is incredibly annoying.

Comment: @ChrisKentfield We have an answer now!

Comment: This issue hasn't been solved in vs2022.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: You just made my life so much better. Is there a way to remap these to Tab, I wonder...?

Comment: I have VS2013, and neither enter nor space prevent it from overwriting. :(

Comment: I withdraw my above comment. You need to toggle completion mode with Ctrl+Alt+Space or go Edit > Intellisense > Toggle Completion Mode.

Comment: Not so good for me, when I just write a part of a word and hit space or enter, I actually type a space or newline. It only works when I begin selecting suggestions with arrows, so the next answer is better for me

Answer (score 17):

With Reshaper 2018.3 I found this is how to disable the behavior you're encountering

Go to `Resharper` -> `Options` -> `Enviroment` -> `Intellisense` -> `Completing Characters`

For the option `Tab Key` choose `Insert` instead of the default `Replace`

Answer (score 1):

I cured this in Visual Studio 2015 (resharper ultimate 2016.3.1) by disabling Resharper IntelliSense.

Go to...

Resharper -> Options -> Environment -> IntelliSense -> General

...and select "Visual Studio".