# How to prevent VS Code from deleting the next word characters on IntelliSense auto-completion?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

This question is analogous to [How to keep Visual Studio autocomplete from overwriting the next word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22075360/1027706),
but targeted at Visual Studio Code instead of Visual Studio.

When a completion suggestion is selected from the list, it is inserted, but all characters from the word after the cursor are deleted. (So, nothing happens if there is a whitespace after the cursor. But if autocompletion is triggered while the cursor is placed at the beginning of a word, said word will be deleted).

Is there a way to disable this deletion behavior and get it to add the selected suggestion without deleting text to the right of the caret?

Comment: Loosely related: [Difference between "acceptSelectedSuggestion" and "acceptAlternativeSelectedSuggestion" in VSCode keybinding config](/q/75403131)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check your [settings.json files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) (your user `settings.json` and your workspace `.vscode/settings.json`).

You probably have a line that says:

```json
"editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace"
```

You can either delete it to get the default behaviour, which is `"insert"` instead of `"replace"`, or just change it to `"insert"`.

The setting's description says:

> Controls whether words are overwritten when accepting completions. Note that this depends on extensions opting into this feature.

The `"insert"` value's description says:

> Insert suggestion without overwriting text right of the cursor.

The `"replace"` value's description says:

> Insert suggestion and overwrite text right of the cursor.

For some languages, the default might be changed. You can check all default settings by viewing the defaultSettings.json file using the `Preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)` command.

To set settings per-[language](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_language-identifier), enclose them in blocks like this (example for C++):

```json
"[cpp]": {
    "editor.suggest.insertMode": "insert"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Mine both user and workspace are on "insert" but it's still acting as "replace". Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @RezaTaba what language are you using? I just answered a related question about a C# extension bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76477336/11107541

Comment: @RezaTaba It's a newly introduced bug https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/5801