# Why does my code get deleted when going back over it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I'm using VS Code (specifically with C#) I will be able to write code just fine but if I ever want to go back and add something in front of another line of code it just writes over what's there.

Example:

```
int maxHealth = 100;
```

Then for example I'll try to add the keyword "public" in front of "int" but instead just writes over it to something like below:

```
publicxHealth = 100;
```

I've looked through settings and tried looking it up online but I don't even know what it's called so I don't know what else to look at.

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: If you're triggering suggestion acceptance, see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/76476072/11107541 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/75448674/11107541