# VSCode Intellisense detects options but inserts nothing

Tags: visual-studio-code

Intellisense does correctly detect the options correctly. However when I press Enter or click on the option, vscode simply dismisses the tooltip without adding the character. Sometimes it even deletes previous characters.

[image: Step 1, just before I'm about to enter a symbol that could be autocompleted]

First start with some code, just before I enter a symbol to be autocompleted.

[image]

Next I type in `_Pro`, which correctly autodetects `_Process(double delta)`. The method I want to override.

[image]

Then, I either press Enter or click on `_Process(double delta)`. Both of which lead me to this outcome. VSCode literally deletes some of the characters I already put in. In other instances it might delete more, or less, or even none. This happens even if I wait 60+ seconds before enter/click.

It works correctly sometimes, like autocompleting variable access even on other classes.

I tried deleteting vscode, deleting my settings file, restarting vscode, restarting the computer.

[image]

I've also seen a few bug report show this modal which I believe debugs intellisense target.

Help: About

Version: 1.82.1 (user setup)
Commit: 6509174151d557a81c9d0b5f8a5a1e9274db5585
Date: 2023-09-08T08:45:05.575Z
Electron: 25.8.0
ElectronBuildId: 23503258
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

Extension causing it: C# v2.1.2 by Microsoft

As far as I can tell only happens when autocompleting overriden methods in C#. It happens both when I let the autocomplete modal show up naturally and when I hit ctrl+space to bring it up.

```
2023-09-15 21:02:15.663 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Enter, keyCode: 13, key: Enter
2023-09-15 21:02:15.663 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Enter, keyCode: 3 ('Enter')
2023-09-15 21:02:15.663 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving Enter
2023-09-15 21:02:15.663 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 27 keybinding entries, matched acceptSelectedSuggestion, when: acceptSuggestionOnEnter && suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionMakesTextEdit && textInputFocus, source: built-in.
2023-09-15 21:02:15.663 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Invoking command acceptSelectedSuggestion.
```

Comment: Does this happen for language modes other than C#? (try some other lanugages such as JS or HTML) Does this happen in all contexts in C#? (try triggering suggestions in other places in your C# files). Does this happen when triggering suggestions manually? Or does it only happen when quick suggestions appear (appear without you manually triggering the suggestions widget to appear)

Comment: hm. I don't see the part where you answered my question about checking if this happens for suggestions in other language modes, or whether it happens only for the particular C# example you showed, or for any other C# suggestions.

Comment: Only C#, only when trying to autocomplete overriden functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# suggestions are replacing subsequent text in VS Code. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76476072/c-sharp-suggestions-are-replacing-subsequent-text-in-vs-code-why). hmmm. but weird that you're getting it on this version of the C# extension where it's supposed to be fixed. maybe it regresed or wasn't completely fixed.