VS Code replaces code with the suggestion instead of inserting it
When I use a code bit like this:
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<UI_Element>> getVectorShallowCopy()
and I try to insert a class name in front of the function (since it's a member function), it always replaces the function name together with inserting the suggestion. Instead of:
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<UI_Element>> ui_elements::getVectorShallowCopy()
I am getting:
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<UI_Element>> ui_elements()
when I press Tab/Enter (which does not matter).
My settings regarding this issue are these:
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "smart",
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": true,
"editor.tabCompletion": "on",
"editor.suggestSelection": "recentlyUsed",
"search.useReplacePreview": false

I do not have the IDEA extension installed, as another question pointed out, and my keybindings do not reflect anything regarding replace on tab either. The behaviour is all the same with pressing Enter instead of Tab.
How can I fix this behaviour?

does https://stackoverflow.com/q/75448674/11107541 answer your question?
